Is the Luminose Tower Loop EXP slower than any battle method?
This answer about "how long does it take to get from level 1 to level 100?" by biking around the Lumiose Tower suggests:

I highly suggest using the restaurants or Battle Chateau to level Pokemon far more efficiently.

With a link to this question:
Is there a way to level up your pokemon easily without leaving it in the Day Care Centre?
However, are any of those answers faster than the approximate 14 EXP a second from the Tower, when assuming all the items have been acquired and equipped, but counting the waits for O-Power to regenerate, and needing to heal the Pokemon?
